How to send post-request with telegram bot to website?
I'am trying to create a telegram bot which will send request to website.
Bot answers at "/fill" message, but doesn't send request.
What am I doing wrong?
Here is my code:
import requests
import telebot
from telebot import types

token = '***********************'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def start(message):
    if message.text == '/fill':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Please write user's score.")

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def handler(message):
    url = 'https://site.ru/assets/requesthandler.php'
    post_params = {'action': 'setParamValue', 'value': message.text}
    resp = requests.post(url, data=post_params)
    if resp.status_code == 200:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Data saved successfully.")
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Something went wrong.")

bot.polling()

